# How to proceed with this Second Order PDE?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I would really like to solve the following with the method you will see below. I have done some work but I have no idea how to continue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

$$
\frac{\partial u(x, t)}{\partial t} = -k(x)u(x, t) 
+A\frac{\partial u(x, t)}{\partial x}+B\frac{\partial^{2}u(x, t)}{\partial x^{2}}
$$

$$ u(x, 0) = 1 $$

Where ... lets say:

$A = 0.05, \ B = 0.5, \ k(x) = 0.5x^{2}$

and Boundary Conditions:

$ u(0, t) = 0, \ u(5, t) = 1 $

---

$ \\ $

Assume: $ u(x, t) = \phi (x)T(t) \\ $

$
\frac{\partial u(x, t)}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial(\phi (x)T(t))}{\partial t} 
 = \phi (x)T^{\prime}(t)
$

$
A\frac{\partial u(x, t)}{\partial x} = A\frac{\partial(\phi (x)T(t))}{\partial x} 
 = A\phi ^{\prime}(x)T(t)
$

$
B\frac{\partial^{2}u(x, t)}{\partial x^{2}} = B\frac{\partial^{2}(\phi (x)T(t))}{\partial x^{2}} 
 = B\frac{\partial(\phi ^{\prime}(x))}{\partial x}T(t) = B\phi ^{\prime\prime}(x)T(t) \\
$

Once, all terms are defined - write out the whole equation:

$
\phi (x)T^{\prime}(t) = -k(x)\phi (x)T(t) 
+A\phi ^{\prime}(x)T(t)+B\phi ^{\prime\prime}(x)T(t) \\
$

Manipulate it a little bit, set it equal to some constant:

$
\frac{T^{\prime}(t)}{T(t)} = \frac{-k(x)\phi (x)}{\phi (x)}+A\frac{\phi ^{\prime}(x)}{\phi (x)} +B\frac{\phi ^{\prime\prime}(x)}{\phi (x)} 
$

$
\frac{T^{\prime}(t)}{T(t)} = 
\frac{-k(x)\phi (x)+A\phi ^{\prime}(x)+B\phi ^{\prime\prime}(x)}{\phi (x)}
 = -\lambda 
$

We end up with two separate equations:

$
T^{\prime}(t)+\lambda T(t) = 0 
$

and

$
-k(x){\phi (x)}+A\phi ^{\prime}(x)+B\phi ^{\prime\prime}(x) 
+\lambda \phi (x) = 0
$

I do not know how to continue beyond this point...

Comment: Hey Edvin. I looked into the problem a little. It actually doesn't look like this equation can be solved generally with separation of variables. Assuming $u(x,t) = X(x)T(t)$ and using the initial condition $u(x,0) = 1$ gives $X(x)T(0) = 1$. Thus $X(x)$ is constant and $X(x) = \frac{1}{T(0)}$. Thus we have $u(x,t) = \frac{T(t)}{T(0)}$. Plugging into the original equation and simplifying gives $T'(t) = -k(x) T(t)$. If $k(x)$ is constant, this has a solution. If $k(x)$ is not constant, it implies $T(t) = 0$ and $u(x,t) = 0$ (which violates our initial condition).

Comment: Depending on why you need this equation solve, you could take a perturbation approach to get an asymptotic expansion for $u(x,t)$ that would be uniformly valid everywhere but in the corner of the origin (due to the discontinuity in the boundary conditions).  If you'd like, I could show you what I mean.  If you are in need of an exact analytic solution however, this isn't for you.

Comment: @Merkh  Yes, I would love to see that. I would be very grateful if you could keep the notation as simple as possible, define all the variables, and write it like you are teaching a little kid. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

**First observation:** your boundary conditions are not consistent. If your left boundary condition is $u(0,t) = 0$, while the initial condition is $u(x,0) = 1$, then these conditions do not match at $(x,t) = (0,0)$. So, let's take a look at two situations: **a)** ignoring the initial condition, and **b)** ignoring the left boundary condition. We're going to try tackle both situations with separation of variables. Following the analysis in your question (which is entirely correct), we end up with two equations:
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2}\phi'' + \frac{1}{20} \phi' - \left(\frac{x^2}{2}-\lambda\right) \phi = 0 \tag{1}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
 T' + \lambda T = 0. \tag{2}
\end{equation}
The solution to $(2)$ is very easy: we obtain $T(t) = T_0 e^{-\lambda t}$. The solution to the second ODE can be expressed in terms of the [Hermite polynomial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HermitePolynomial.html) and the [hypergeometric function $_1F_1$](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric1F1/), as
\begin{equation}
 e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x}{20}} \left[c_1 \,H_{-\lambda-\frac{401}{800}}(x) + c_2 \phantom{1}_1 F_1(\frac{401}{1600}+\frac{\lambda}{2},\frac{1}{2},x^2)\right]. \tag{3}
\end{equation}

**a)** Ignoring the initial condition, we have to find a way to incorporate the boundary conditions $u(0,t) = 0$ and $u(5,t) = 1$. From $u(x,t) = T(t) \phi(x)$, the left boundary condition gives $\phi(0) = 0$, since $T(t) = T_0 e^{-\lambda t}$ is only zero if $T_0 = 0$, which would yield the trivial solution $u = 0$; this trivial solution obviously does not satisfy the right boundary condition $u(5,t) = 1$.

This right boundary condition yields for the general solution $T(t) \phi(5) = 1$. This implies that $T(t)$ is *constant* in $t$, which in turn implies that $T_0=0$, violating the right boundary condition.

We conclude that a solution obtained by separation of variables cannot obey the right boundary condition $u(5,t) = 1$. Note that changing this boundary condition to $u(5,t) = 0$ could be a way forward, since the equations $\phi(0) = 0$ and $\phi(5) = 0$ can be used to determine the constants $c_1$ and $c_2$ in $(3)$.

**b)** Ignoring both boundary conditions for the moment, we try to incorporate the initial condition $u(x,0) = 1$. In terms of the solution obtained by separation of variables, this means that $T(0) \phi(x) = T_0 \phi(x) = 1$. This means that $\phi(x)$ is *constant* in $x$. One way to make sure this happens is to choose $c_1 = c_2 = 0$, but this would yield $\phi(x) = 0$, violating the initial condition. Therefore, the alternative would be to look for $\lambda$-values for which both the Hermite polynomial and the hypergeometric function are equal to $e^{\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x}{20}}$. However, from the ODE $(1)$, we already see that the only constant solution is the zero solution: if $\phi(x) = \frac{1}{T_0}$, then $\phi' = 0$ and $\phi'' = 0$, yielding (see $(1)$)
\begin{equation}
\left(\frac{x^2}{2}-\lambda\right)\phi = 0,
\end{equation}
which can only be true for all $x \in (0,5)$ if $\phi = 0$. So, a solution obtained by separation of variables cannot obey the initial condition $u(x,0) = 1$.

**To conclude:** If you want have a chance to obtain a solution to this equation by separation of variables, choose different boundary conditions.

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for you answer. How did you get from (1) to (3) ? Could you show some steps please? That is really what I am looking for.

Comment: Well, I asked Mathematica. It is worthwhile to substitute $\phi(x) = f(x)\,\text{exp}[-\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x}{20}]$ and find an equation for $f(x)$, which should be equivalent to the ODE for $_1 F_1$. However, aren't you worried about the problems with the boundary and initial conditions?

Comment: The initial condition is correct - the boundary conditions I just threw in there.  Also, I am more interested in learning a method rather than just knowing the single solution to the equation...

Answer (score -1):

The PDE isn't nonlinear; it is linear. It is only non-linear if $u$ shows up in some non-linear function. Like if there was a $u^2$ or an $e^u$ or $u \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}$ then it would be nonlinear. But this equation has nothing like that.

From where you are, you have $$B\phi'' + A\phi' + \lambda \phi = \tfrac 1 2 x^2, \,\,\,\,\,\, \phi(0) = 0, \phi(5) = 1.$$ To solve this, you need a particular solution and a homogeneous solution. For the particular solution, since you have a polynomial on the right hand side, you can just guess $$\phi_p(x) = \alpha x^2 + \beta x + \gamma,$$ plug it in and just solve for $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ in terms of $A,B,\lambda$. For the homogeneous solution, you can guess $$\phi_h(x) = Ce^{mx},$$ where $C$ is an arbitrary constant. When you plug this in, you get a quadratic equation for $m$; solving this gives two roots, $m_+$ and $m_-$ (where the $\pm$ corresponds to the $\pm$ in the quadratic formula). Then your full solution for $\phi$ is $$\phi(x) = \phi_p(x) + \phi_h(x) = \alpha x^2 + \beta x + \gamma + C_1e^{m_+x} + C_2 e^{m_-x}$$ and you need to pick $C_1, C_2$ so that the boundary conditions are satisfied.

For $T$ the procedure is similar, but the equation is much easier: $$T' + \lambda T = 0, \,\,\,\, T(0) = 1$$ gives $T(t) = e^{-\lambda t}.$

Comment: But I do not know $λ$ - There could be an infinite number of them. That is why I did not define it. Am I correct?

Comment: In order to satisfy the boundary conditions (i.e. the conditions on $\phi$), you will likely need $\lambda$ to satisfy certain conditions. It's likely that only finitely many or countably many $\lambda$ will work. Solve the equation for each $\lambda$ that works to get $\phi_{\lambda}(x)$ and the corresponding $T_\lambda(t)$. Then since the equation is linear and homogeneous, the full solution is $$u(x,t) = \sum_{\lambda}\phi_{\lambda}(x) T_{\lambda}(t)$$

Comment: I am sorry - I am not that smart. Can you please add an example to your reply - how to find one Lambda that satisfies the BCs.

Comment: Sure, I'll do it for the usual heat equation. It'll be added in a few minutes.

Comment: Thank you so much. I think it would be ideal if you use this example instead of introducing new equations. But again, I will take whatever I can get.

Comment: Sorry, it was going to take too long. Here is a reference with many examples. You can follow the procedure in the examples. You're particular equation is not going to have a particularly pretty solution but essentially it's just an algebra/low lever diff eq problem once you've separated variables: http://www.math.psu.edu/wysocki/M412/Notes412_7.pdf

Comment: I understand - its ok. I actually have that PDF but I have not been able to apply it to my equation. They make some assumptions there, such as lambdas as sine functions, that I don't understand.

Comment: I added a bounty if would like to finish the problem. Thank you.

Comment: Just FYI - I had a term error in my last equation. I fixed it.